# Logstash vs Apache Flink for real time data logging

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working on building a dashboard where feeds are provided in real time by a Java Application. I want to utilize Elasticsearch and Kibana to analyze over these feeds. But I am confused if I should use Logstash or Apache Flink to log data or should I directly log data into Elasticsearch?